# How to let site:example.com show results?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, web-crawlers, sitemap

I set up a website `example.com` several months ago but it does not show up in `site:example.com`, so I submitted it in Google search console. After several days, I saw there were some pages indexed in Google search console, but `site:example.com` still shows nothing. I want to know under what conditions are the indexed pages shown by `site:example.com`, or the `site:` instruction is useless nowadays like the `link:` instruction?

Answer (score 3):

You should get at least one result: the homepage.

Check two things:

1. if the usage is correct, just site: and just the domain name without http/s or www
2. in Google Search Console type your homepage url at the top, where it says "inspect any URL in..".

If it's indexed (and you say it is), but Google doesn't show it, it may be because it's too new or the domain has some past penalties. Ultimately, turn off the safe search in case it's an adult type of result.

The site: operator is still used, here is the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators/all-search-site

Comment: site: is not an accurate tool. Use the reports in Google Search Console to know what is indexed. And even that can be delayed from reality.

Comment: The usage is correct, but site:example.com does not show any web page, even the homepage. Inspecting url in google search console shows homepage is not indexed but other pages are indexed. I don't see any sign of penalty in google search console.

Comment: @William See the Limitations section at the bottom of this Google help document on the [site: search operator](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators/all-search-site): `The site: operator doesn't necessarily return all the URLs that are indexed under the prefix specified in the query.`

Comment: @dan Yes, I know that. But I'm surprised by the fact that it does not return any url.

Answer (score 0):

Google is always slow at indexing a new site.  It can take weeks to months before it is trusted enough to be indexed fully.  You need to use the Search Console to find out why.

1. Try the `site:domain` command  on other search engines?
2. Submit to Bing and Yandex.  They both provide better feedback if there are issues with your page, especially Yandex.
3. Use a site checking tool, I use Ahrefs, it is free for small sites and will provide you with some feedback.